# MySQL Multiple row update failure

Tags: php, mysql

Am attempting to update multiple records in a table all at once when a user clicks on the submit button of the form. My code only updates the first row and does nothing to the rest, no error. Below is the code am working with on post

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $subject_id = $_POST["subject_id"];
    $student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
    $test1 = $_POST["test1"];
    $test2 = $_POST["test2"];
    $test3 = $_POST["test3"];

    for($i=0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
        $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_id[$i]);
        $subjectid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);
        $test_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test1[$i]);
        $test_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test2[$i]);
        $test_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test3[$i]);

        $query = "UPDATE records SET test1='{$test_1}', test2='{$test_2}', test3='{$test_3}' WHERE student_id={$studentid} AND subject_id={$subjectid}";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($result) { 
            redirect_to("dashboard.php");
        } else {
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
            exit;
        }
    }
   }
?>
```

What could be responsible for only the first row being updated and the others ignored? Questions similar to multiple row update haven't helped much as they seem different from what am trying to do here.

Comment: What about this line. $subjectid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id); You have not passed the $i in to $subject_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In loop you made `redirect_to("dashboard.php");` so it probably exit the loop ;)

Comment: Closing the loop before redirecting solved it. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Redirect condition placed wrongly. Find the below code.
        
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
$subject_id = $_POST["subject_id"];
$student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
$test1 = $_POST["test1"];
$test2 = $_POST["test2"];
$test3 = $_POST["test3"];

for($i=0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_id[$i]);
    $subjectid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);
    $test_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test1[$i]);
    $test_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test2[$i]);
    $test_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test3[$i]);

    $query = "UPDATE records SET test1='{$test_1}', test2='{$test_2}', test3='{$test_3}' WHERE student_id={$studentid} AND subject_id={$subjectid}";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$result) { 
        break;
    } 
}
if(!$result){
  echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
  exit;
}
else {
   redirect_to("dashboard.php");
}} ?>
```